# LED light flickers when TV turns on

Tags: electrical, lighting, troubleshooting

I recently wired a new light fixture with LED bulbs to a dimmer switch (dimmer is compatible with LEDs). This is on a dedicated lighting circuit with an Arc Fault breaker. I used brand new romex 14/2 from panel to switch to light.

On a separate circuit (old BX wiring, ground confirmed) is a receptacle that has a TV, receiver and DVD player plugged in. No Arc Fault breaker for this circuit.

When I turn on the TV, receiver and DVD player (they all turn on at the same time with the remote power button), the LED light flickers once for a small fraction of a second.

If it was on the same circuit, I would guess its the voltage drop affecting the transformers in the LEDs. But at this point, I am unsure because the loads are on separate circuits. Any ideas?

Comment: and when you leave the lights off, and turn on the TV+R+DVD first then turn on the light ? Is the dimmer wifi

Comment: if it exists, change the dip switches on remote and wall plug receiver

Comment: I am not after power surge, but after RF interference. To test, unplug the TV+R+D, then activate with remote without drawing power,

Comment: I don't think it's RF. If I activate the remote without turning the loads on, the light does not flicker.

Comment: If I turn on only the receiver or only the TV, the light does not flicker. If both are turned on at the same time, the light flickers. Also, flicker seems to happen only when the dimmer is turned all the way up. At 7/8, it does not flicker. Not a Wifi dimmer.

Comment: The flicker also happens at the same time that I hear the relays in the receiver click.

Comment: what relays ? what kind of monster is that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem in my living room when I replaced my old flood lights with LEDS on a dimmer. The lights and outlets were on different circuits but on the same bus in the main panel. I changed the lights to the other 120 V bus in the main panel. If you choose to try this, make sure the breaker size is the same. the problem went away.